What is story of Ikshvaku dynasty and It's relation with Vedic Tribes? (I don't want answer according to Purāṇas)
I was studying history and found that at many places kings mention in Vedas have a historical relation. Like Kuru Kings-Janamejaya a Parikṣita were actual Kings mentioned in Atharvaveda.
The kosala kingdom was a real kingdom in ancient India but what is its relation to Ikshvaku and other suryavamshi Kings. At some places Ikshvaku Kings are said to be descendants of Purus.
Please clear my doubts
